# Thunderbird extension - hide number of unread mails

Tags: thunderbird

I'm looking for a Thunderbird extension to hide the number of unread mails next to the inbox/other folders. I organize my mail with tags but keep them unread if I for example will only answer them tomorrow or answered them already, but still want to keep them "visible" to remind me of a task. So the number doesn't represent the amount of emails for this day. That's why I would like to hide it. Didn't find any extension or something similar - any recommendations?

Comment: I ended up solving the "problem" by using this extension and then just hiding the folder pane most of the time.

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quickfolders-tabbed-folders/

It has an option to not display the numbers of unread emails in the folder-tabs.